# Can we measure the black-body radiation/ electromagnetic radiation that pass through some point P in space?

Tags: thermodynamics, astrophysics, astronomy

I was wondering if we can measure the black-body/electromagnetic radiation energy of a point in space without actually knowing the source of this energy.

Let us say 2 stars emit black-body radiation/electromagnetic radiation. This radiation passes through some point $P$. Can we quantitatively measure the radiation passing through this point $P$ without knowing the existence of those 2 stars (The source of the radiation)?

Can we also measure the radiation falling on some arbitrary surface of area A?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can! How effectively depends on the temperature of the radiation and on your instrument, though.

An example is the [Planck mission](https://www.esa.int/Enabling_Support/Operations/Planck) (and its predecessors), which measured the Cosmic Microwave Background radiation, which is very close to a blackbody.

"Knowing the source" is not required in general - you point your detector somewhere, and see what you measure.
You need to account for the field of view of your instrument, though - if the source (say, a star) is outside it, you might not measure anything.
In the CMB case, this was not an issue since it comes from all directions.

Certain detectors, such as optical telescopes, tend to have very narrow FoVs, while for example in order to measure very low-temperature radiation you can use something like a bolometer, which detects it just by heating up, and which is therefore not very directional.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know were can I access some thermal imagery that shows the amount and quantity of radiation around something like planetary systems?

Comment: What do you mean by "thermal imagery"? Are you looking for [exoplanet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exoplanet#:~:text=An%20exoplanet%20or%20extrasolar%20planet,1988%2C%20was%20confirmed%20in%202003.) pictures?

Comment: I mean images taken to planetary systems, like Kepler-62 and its planets, where I can see the amount of radiation (which is created by the star and planets) that surround that system .

Comment: That's likely a question for the Astronomy stack. Still, remember that the Kepler satellite uses transiting photometry: it sees these planetary systems as pointlike and it measures their luminosity as a function of time.